# ldap_bind always returning true

Tags: php, ldap

I'm attempting to implement LDAP user authentification however for some reason no matter what the input is, ldap_bind always returns true. Whether the input is gibberish, empty, or legitimate

```
$ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost)
      or die("Could not connect to $ds");

if($bind = ldap_bind($ds,$username, $password)) 
{
  // login successful
} 
else {
  // error message
}
```

any ideas?

note: using the code below produces the same issue:

```
$bind = ldap_bind($ds,$username, $password);

if($bind) 
{
  // login successful
} 
else {
  // error message
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do like this...

```
 if(ldap_bind($ds,$username, $password))
```

instead of

```
if($bind = ldap_bind($ds,$username, $password))
```

Comment: I want to use an assignment. I'm not making a comparison. I'm simply attempting to indicate whether the ldap_bind is successful or not.

Comment: Replacing the conditional with ldap_bind($ds,$username, $password) still gives me the issue. Also $bind = ldap_bind($ds,$username, $password) followed by if ($bind) still gives me the issue. Even when giving dummy text for username and password

Comment: Was connect to host was successful ?

Comment: Yes. The bind fails when using dummy text for the host.

Comment: Why is the answer marked right if you still have the issue? I have the same issue and the proposed answer is no help, I tried it before I looked on SO

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that finds this question-
It's possible that you are attempting an 'anonymous simple bind' if you're passing a zero length password, which will always return true.

See the comment for better description check out [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php#73718)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ldapmanagment.php with this:

```
    class Connection {

protected $server;
protected $port;
protected $user;
protected $password;
protected $ldapconn;

public function __construct($server, $port, $user, $password){

 $this->server = $server;
 $this->port = $port;
 $this->user = $user;
 $this->password = $password;

 }
 public function connect() {

 $this->ldapconn = ldap_connect($this->server,$this->port) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");




    ldap_set_option($this->ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($this->ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    if ($this->ldapconn) {


            $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($this->ldapconn, $this->user, $this->password);


    }
}
```

and in your file php this:

```
include('ldapmanagement.php');


$connection = new Connection ($LDAPHOST,$LDAPPORT,$ldaprdn,$ldappass);

$connection->connect();
```

Comment: this always returns true for me even when passing fake usernames and passwords

Answer (score 0):

Gagola, the function ldap_bind occurs at the server side. so once the webserver's os user binded to the ldap server, next queries return true.
the solution is simple as unbinding it just after binding it.
here is an example.

```
<?php
function ad_auth( $server, $username, $password ){
    $ldap = @ldap_connect( $server );
    if ( @ldap_bind( $ldap, $username, $password ) ){
            ldap_unbind( $ldap );
            return true;
            }
    else
            return false;
    }
?>
```